# Eclemma or eCobertura execute coverage programatically using java?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, eclemma, ecobertura

I need to execute code coverage programatically  for a project, I have searched and could not find anything helpful, the closest I got was using JaCoCo but I need either Eclemma or eCobertura or preferably both. If anyone can lead me into the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: What was wrong with using JaCoCo?

Comment: It is not approved in my company, we only use emma or ecobertura

Comment: @GlenF. It is strange that EclEmma approved, but not JaCoCo, because under the hood EclEmma is just an UI over JaCoCo.